# Places for the up-to-date topics in robotics

Tags: research

Are there specific places/websites where you guys read about the topics that are being searched in Robotics, specially, for the most newest researches. I would like to know the places where the most hottest topics in Robotics are studied for both theoretical and experimental studies. The only place I know is IEEE community. They are doing great specially their magazine but I'm curious if there are any alternatives for  robotics scientists. Please include journals.

Comment: there are many levels of robotics, from hobbyist, to professional, to production.  please tell us what you'd like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds a bit like a shopping question, but I'll provide what I know.

The IEEE societies have always provided me a wealth of information.  In addition to the Robotics Society, with its magazine and journal (IEEE Transactions on Robotics and Automation), they also host a fantastic annual conference.  But there are other societies with robotics-related content, also.  For example, their Systems, Man, and Cybernetics society has several journals, and many topics directly related to robotics.  They also have societies which focus on systems, medical devices, and industrial applications with relevant content to an aspiring roboticist.

ASME has similar societies with a broad array of relevant content.  Check out their Journal of Mechanisms and Robotics, or papers from their biannual Design Technical Conferences.

The International Journal of Robotics Research was a seminal journal, and continues to be a leading publisher of robotics research.  There's also the Robotics and Autonomous Systems journal, which I have not personally found too related to my interests, but is an active publication.

Springer-Verlang also publishes some interesting collections of research papers, often in book form.  Their series on Advances in Robot Kinematics has been quite interesting to me.

Also, don't forget to include patent office searches.

I'm sure there are dozens more good publications.  I'd recommend finding a topic you're interested in studying, then find a seminal paper on that topic.  Tracing back through the chains of references should point you to the publications that have been most active for that topic.

Comment: I agree. Particularly about starting with people and papers that interest you and following their references.

Answer (score -3):

The IEEE society has a paywall infront of their papers. To read the information, somebody has to choose between paying 30 US$ per paper, or become a member which costs hundreds of dollar per year. Additionally, the quality of the papers is in doubt, because most of the journals of IEEE have no public peer-review. In contrast, the stackoverflow and stackexchange website are a good place for discuss new developments. The quality of the postings is high, and the content is available as fulltext. If you have any questions about current robotics, for example how to win the robocup challange, feel free to ask.